# which will take care memory management in ARC

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

Which will take care in ARC in ios 5.0 or ios 5.1

i am allocated object and need not to release that object in ARC, those ARC take care itself

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc]init];

[customView setFrame:CGRectMake(kRect)];
[self.view addSubview: customView];

[customView release];
```

in ARC customView release it will handle by it self.

What happened if i said release to customView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need not release an object its ARC will take care about the memory once your project create select the ARC auto retain count!  which will take care about the memory management

Answer (score 2):

You cant call `release` since ARC will throw an error if you do so

`Release` is not available in ARC environment, your project wont build

Answer (score 0):

ARC will take care of your memory but stile you want to remove a object from memory you can do simply object=nil; then arc knows that the variable has no use and remove's it from memory.